# R - Building Autoencoder model in Caret

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret, h2o, autoencoder

I want to build an autoencoder model with the Caret package with the following features:

1) Build an unsupervised neural network model using deep learning autoencoders

2) Using the autoencoder model in (1) as a pre-training input for a supervised model.

Online examples on using autoencoder in caret are quite few and far in between, offering no real insight into practical use cases.

I'm under data privacy and resource constraints so I'm unable to use H2o or Keras for neural networks.

Sample data for the model can be found at:
https://www.kaggle.com/nodarokroshiashvili/credit-card-fraud/data

An example of this in H2o is at this link:
https://shiring.github.io/machine_learning/2017/05/01/fraud

Any help or pointers in the right direction in this regard will be appreciated.

EDIT:
Thanks to Lauren and Erin, staff at H20 commenting that data privacy should not be a concern because H20 creates a cluster which is located on premise and not in an 'H20.cloud'

Comment: There are no privacy issues with either H2O or Keras, and H2O will be far more efficient than caret, so I don't really understand the restrictions you're stating.  If you are under resource constraints, H2O is definitely the best option.  Can you explain your concerns further?

Comment: @ErinLeDell 
Data privacy concerns: The data I'm using are quite sensitive and cannot be uploaded into the cloud. My colleague and I have divided opinions on whether H2O uploads into the cloud when you do h2o.init()
Resource constraints: We intend to embed the solution into the SQL machine learning server which only takes R and python currently. Not sure how to initialize H2O in the SQL server.

Please shed more light on whether our concerns are valid or possible ways that we can circumvent the concerns.

Comment: whether h2o launches a cluster locally or in the cloud is completely under your control. Please read the following documentation resources on launching h2o with .init() http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/articles/h2o-r-package.html#overview, http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.init.html or with security: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/security.html?highlight=security.

Comment: @Lauren 
Thanks for the links, it sheds light on the debate I had on data security/privacy.
Do you have suggestions on how H2O can be used in the SQL server for machine learning?

Comment: @user1783739 you can find information on relational databases here http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html?highlight=sql#jdbc-databases. If possible, please edit your post, if you no longer have privacy concerns about H2O. thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as an "H2O cloud" owned by H2O.ai which captures your training data.  H2O can be used on a cloud computing service (e.g. AWS), but that instance would be controlled by you.

Comment: @Lauren the link you sent is specifically for PostgreSQL and MySQL, any links for Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: @Lauren Just saw this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851748/how-to-load-table-from-sql-server-using-h2o-in-r, thoughts?